# Why do random spawning labels speed up another moving label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, geometry, label

I am making a cat and mouse type game (just for fun and to learn about bind etc.), one label is controlled by the arrow keys, the other one follows it, chasing it a bit slower. I decided to add a bonus label which randomly spawns within a certain area every x seconds (every second at the moment). The problem is that this extra code for some reason makes the 'cat' label chase faster and speed up in strange areas.

**This is the bonus label spawning code:**

```
def prizes():
    ran1 = random.randint(0, 600)
    ran2 = random.randint(0, 500)
    prize = tk.Label(bg = 'red', text = 'Bonus')
    prize.place(x = ran1, y = ran2)
    root.after(1000, prizes)
```

My ICT teacher thought that the random speed up could be due to the geometry size of the mainloop window, what I do is maximise the window when I run the code, could this be the reason?

**Try this code and maximise the window, run around for a bit (go to the right of the screen and wait for the random speed ups.):**
I apologise for the global variables, its just a game made for fun.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg = 'yellow')
root.geometry("1350x720")
runner = tk.Label(text = 'Mouse', bg = 'green')
global no1
global no2
no1 = 400
no2 = 300
runner.place(x = no1, y = no2)
def leftbutton(event):
    global no1
    no1 -= 3
    runner.place(x = no1, y = no2)
def rightbutton(event):
    global no1
    no1 += 3
    runner.place(x = no1, y = no2)
def upbutton(event):
    global no2
    no2 -= 3
    runner.place(x = no1, y = no2)
def downbutton(event):
    global no2
    no2 += 3
    runner.place(x = no1, y = no2)
global num1
global num2
num1 = 50
num2 = 50
chaser = tk.Label(bg = 'lightblue', text = 'CAT')
chaser.place(x = num1, y = num2)
global var
var = 2

def prizes():
    ran1 = random.randint(0, 600)
    ran2 = random.randint(0, 500)
    prize = tk.Label(bg = 'red', text = 'Bonus')
    prize.place(x = ran1, y = ran2)
    root.after(1000, prizes)

def start():
    global var
    if var == 2:
        prizes()
        begin.destroy()
    var = 1
    global num1
    global num2
    global no1
    global no2
    chaser.place(x = num1, y = num2)
    if num1 > no1:
        num1 -=1
    if num1 < no1:
        num1 += 1
    if num2 > no2:
        num2 -= 1
    if num2 < no2:
        num2 += 1
    if num2 == no2 and num1 == no1:
        root.destroy()
        print('You Lose, GAME OVER')
    else:
        root.after(1, start)
begin = tk.Button(bg = 'pink', text = "BEGIN GAME", command = start)
begin.place(x = 1, y = 1)
root.bind("<Left>", leftbutton)
root.bind("<Right>", rightbutton)
root.bind("<Up>", upbutton)
root.bind("<Down>", downbutton)
root.mainloop()
```

**But, when you omit the function `prizes`, and the line where it is called, you get a perfect chasing cat, which doesn't speed up.** Why does the prizes function at the top make the 'cat' label speed up?

Comment: Every second you are creating _another_ bonus label. Is that intentional, or do you want a single bonus label that moves around?

Comment: I can't duplicate the speedup -- it all seems to run at the same speed for me, and I don't see anything in your code that would cause it to speed up.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Another bonus label every second is intended, they don't do anything yet but will. Maybe you aren't waiting long enough for the speed up to occur, it takes some time, but does happen, maybe it was the computer I was using, ill try others maybe they'll help.

Comment: It would appear that the computer I was using didn't like me, it works at home, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more likely to do with that there is nothing in your code that regulates the speed of your animation. The reason that your animation is more stable on a different computer could be to do with your application getting a more even share of the resources on the second machine, this making your animation play at a more constant rate.

Depending on your machine factors such as network activity, disk activity, ram size, swap size, graphics cards, disk fragmentation etc etc etc could all affect the speed at which a free wheeling piece of code runs (I.e. Code which makes no attempt to regulate it's own speed)

You should research timing loops and frame rates, but basically your code should try to regulate the animation rate itself - one common technique is to decide how often to do an animation frame (say once every 1/25s) and use a simple clock/sleep technique to ensure that you only animate that fast.

Btw : a sample size of two is not a big enough sample with which to draw any conclusions, about your code, or your computers.

Answer (score 1):

A bit like Tony said, your code isn't the issue, but rather the fact that no two computers are exactly the same. We can guess what is wrong with one of them, but will never truly know, and you cannot really solve this, except for avoiding the computer in question or by regulating your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it appears that the problem was not to do with the code for the bonus labels (although it must have played a part), but more **an issue with the computer I was using**. It appears that the above code works with most (?) computers, but the one I was on was not one of them.

Comment: See my answer, it is likely to be far less a problem with your computer, and far more likely to be due to missing features in your code.